# Multiple plots factor by ID and Day

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

Hi I am trying to plot multiple plots factor by ID and DAY. Each ID will have multiple plots based on the day, all ID's have multiple day data so multiple plots. I tried with the lattice plot as shown below. But factor with both day and ID is an issue.

```
library("lattice")
# require("lattice") - you do not need this line
xyplot(IPRE+PRED+DV) ~ TIME| ID, data= df ,type=c("l","l","p"),col= c("blue","black","red"),
       distribute.type=TRUE, xlab="Time (h)",ylab="conc",layout=c(0,4))
```

[Columns ID DAY TIME DV IPRED PRED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c5Fi.jpg)

Comment: Please try to format your code properly and provide an reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what your ultimate goal is but this may be of some assistance. `facet_wrap` from the `ggplot` package allows you to split the plots by multiple variables.

```
library(ggplot2)

data(iris)

iris$Day<-rep(weekdays(Sys.Date()+0:4),each=10)

ggplot(data=iris,aes(x=Sepal.Width,y=Sepal.Length))+
  geom_point(aes(colour=Species))+
               facet_wrap(~Day+Species,nrow=5)
```

[image]